# Multiple files uploading on Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, paperclip

I would like to upload multiple pictures to my Rails 3 application. I am currently using Paperclip to upload a picture, and I have some post processing operations assigned to the model Photo.

I saw some samples on the net (integrating uploadify, swfupload or some other libraries), but none was very detailed, and each one misses some steps.
What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

A good JQuery uploader is  [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) . It has some paperclip samples and you can find a demo [here](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

```
@params = {
    "FacialImage" => UploadIO.new(File.new('C:\temp\ATDD\Test\test\sachin.jpg'), "image/jpeg"),
    "Login" => UploadIO.new(File.new('C:\temp\ATDD\Test\test\login.txt'), "application/json")
}
```

Comment: It's not clear how this answers the question at all. Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.