# Multiple file upload with paperclip using rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Hi i want to upload mulitiple file using rails 3 and paperclip please help or please tell me

about any link to do this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try out this.......

https://github.com/Emerson/Multiple-File-Uploads-with-Paperclip-and-Rails-3

http://swfupload.org/project/swfupload

Answer (score 0):

we have been talking about this before!

Take a look at this question:
[Multiple files uploading on Ruby on Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018407/multiple-files-uploading-on-ruby-on-rails-3)